# starting in 1950

Tags: dangling-modifier

Suppose there were an exhibition about the cartoon series that have been broadcast since 1950. Would the following be an example of a dangling modifier?

> **Starting** in 1950 with Atomic Kitten, visitors explore several collections of art devoted each cartoon series.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: "devoted **to** each" is more contemporary.  "devoted each" is grammatical but rather 19th century.

Comment: And the visitors would "start **with**" not "in".  *Starting with Atomic Kitten from 1950, visitors explore...*

Comment: And of course **each** here assumes you've already mentioned these series in an earlier sentence not included in your quoted snippet.

Comment: Does "Starting with Aromic Kitten from 1950"  modify "visitors" or "several collections of art"?

Comment: It "modifies" the main clause in its entirety. I would say that it "attends" the main clause. You can move it to the end of the sentence if you like.

Comment: You could imagine 1950 as referring to that section of the museum's display, not to the year per se, and then **in** would work too.  It would be a virtual representation of the year, not the year itself.  But **with** is simpler.

Comment: It's not a dangling modifier. *Starting* is directly linked with *visitors explore*, so it makes sense.